# References on number of features to use in Random Forest Regression

Tags: random-forest, cart

The default number of features $m$ used when making splits in a random forest regression is $m=p$ in Python's sklearn, where $p$ is the number of predictors in the regression problem (see [the sklearn docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html): If `auto`, then `max_features`=`n_features`).  In R's randomForest package, the default number of features used when making splits in a regression problem is $m=p\,/\,3$ (see [the randomForest docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf), and specifically the `mtry` argument to `randomForest`).

This point is (briefly) discussed at https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7254, where an sklearn contributor says that $m=p$ is recommended. I've seen the $m=p\,/\,3$ recommendation in several places (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939750/understanding-max-features-parameter-in-randomforestregressor and https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf)

My general understanding is that $m$ should always be tuned in random forest regression problems, and that the optimal $m$ could vary depending on the setting. Are there any references that discuss $m$ specifically in the context of regression (as opposed to classification)?  Is there any well-founded reason to prefer either R's or sklearn's default value for $m$ (or should the answer be "don't use the default, always tune," so that the default doesn't matter)?

Comment: I've always been suspicious that the default is straight bagging.  There are other bizarre defaults in sklearn, `subsample = 1.0` in gradient boosting.

Comment: Authoritative literature on selecting values of m is hard to find. Leo Breiman's paper https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/randomforest2001.pdf uses log(M + 1) where M is number of variables. But gives experimental justification. I guess log or square roots or even n_features/constants are used  to reduced computation cost and not for accuracy arguments. So tuning should be the way to go, but albeit not using the sklearn default.

Comment: What's wrong with the paper that the github link you posted links to? They vary the choice of $m$ from $1$ to $p$ and show that in almost all cases *for regression* their best results were at $m=p$

Comment: @Dan the accepted answer (below) covers that point:  "However, the paper they cite is about 'extremely randomized trees', not standard random forests. Extremely randomized trees choose completely random split points, whereas random forests optimize the split point."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to *Elements of Statistical Learning* (section 15.3):

- Recommended default values are $m = p/3$ for regression problems and $m = \sqrt{p}$ for classification problems (attributed to Breiman)
- The best value of $m$ depends on the problem, so $m$ should be treated as a tuning parameter.

As discussed by Breiman (2001), the generalization error of a random forest decreases with the generalization error of the individual trees, and with the correlation between trees. Subsampling features is a way to decorrelate the trees. Increasing $m$ makes individual trees more powerful, but also increases their correlation. The optimal value of $m$ achieves a tradeoff between these two opposing effects, and typically lies somewhere in the middle of the range. He states that, in regression problems (compared to classification problems), the generalization error of individual trees decreases more slowly with $m$, and the correlation between trees increases more slowly. So, a larger value of $m$ is needed. This would explain why the commonly recommended default values for $m$ scale faster with $p$ for regression problems than classification problems. However, I didn't see an explicit recommendation for $m = p/3$ in this paper.

Regarding scikit-learn's default setting of $m=p$: As mentioned above, subsampling features is one of the essential properties of random forests, and improves their performance by decorrelating the trees. Setting $m=p$ would remove this benefit, and would make the model equivalent to simple bagged trees. Breiman (2001) showed that this gives inferior performance on regression problems. Someone on the scikit-learn github page you linked claimed that $m=p$ is indeed recommended. However, the paper they cite is about 'extremely randomized trees', not standard random forests. Extremely randomized trees choose completely random split points, whereas random forests optimize the split point. As above, good performance requires a balance between strengthening the individual trees and injecting randomness to decorrelate them. Because extremely randomized trees inject a higher degree of randomness in the split points, it makes sense that they would benefit by compensating with searching over more features to split on. Conversely, random forests fully optimize the split points, so it makes sense that they would benefit by subsampling features to increase randomness.

References:

[Breiman (2001)](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/randomforest2001.pdf). Random Forests.

[Hastie, Tibshirani, Friedman (2009)](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/). The Elements of Statistical Learning.

Comment: +1, but why are these values recommended, and why do other authors disagree? I'm aware of the ESLII recommendation, but where does it come from?

Comment: I edited the post to add more information. Hopefully it addresses your questions a bit more. Regardless of any default values, I think the proper approach is to tune $m$